# Override Getter in Controller

Tags: grails, groovy

I don't appear to be able to override a getter within my grails controller.  The sample code I've created to illustrate this is provided below:

```
class MyController extends RestfulController<MyDomainObj> {

    def field
    def getField(){
        field += 1
    }

    def index(MyCommand command) {
        field = 1
        // in a controller this prints 1, but in my class it prints 2
        println('field' + field)  
    }
}
```

If I create a Groovy class and override the getter then it works.

```
class X {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        def x = new X()
        x.field = 1
        println x.field
    }

    def field
    def getField(){
        field += 1
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in the Controller or is this feature not supported in controllers?  If it isn't supported, then does anyone know why?  What magic is going on that would cause this feature not to work?

Comment: I would imagine this works from the regular groovy class because you are accessing the field using an instance of the object from a static context (which uses Groovy magic to call the getter). In the controller, it is merely accessing the instance property `field`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For attributes within a class, Groovy uses the generated private variable directly:

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans:

> If you access a property from within the class the property is defined
>   in at compile time with implicit or explicit this (for example
>   this.foo, or simply foo), Groovy will access the field directly
>   instead of going though the getter and setter.

Example:

```
class C {

    def prop

    def getProp() {
            println "getter"
            prop
    }

    def dostuff() {
            prop = "Y"
            println prop
            println getProp()
    }

}

new C().dostuff()
```

results in

```
Y
getter
Y
```

Comment: Hmm. Do you know a way around that?

Comment: @CharlesWood the easiest way around would be to declare the var private (and even name it differently) and provide your own getter (and setter).